# Linq in datatable or data set

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a `list<string>` and a DataSet. I need to write a Linq query to get the values from dataset or datatable to check if the values are present in `List<string>`. Please help me in writing the query to get datas from dataset or datatable

i will use foreach after getting the values to check whether the data is present in `list<string>`

**EDIT:**

```
DataSet dsDuplicate = (DataSet) Session["EventDescription"];
DataTable dt = dsDuplicate.Tables[0];
string cellValue = string.Empty;
for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < gvEventMechanic.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
{
     TextBox textBoxId = (TextBox)gvEventMechanic.Rows[rowCount].Cells[2].FindControl("txtId");
     lstStringId.Add(textBoxId.Text);
}
```

Comment: we need more information, and any previous code that you may have written. This question is far to broad.

Comment: What do you expect to get returned to you? The values of all objects in the dataTable if the are also contained in the list<string>?

Comment: I have a value in DataSet i just need to check if it is present in List also..

Comment: DataSet dsDuplicate = (DataSet) Session["EventDescription"]; DataTable dt = dsDuplicate.Tables[0]; string cellValue = string.Empty; for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < gvEventMechanic.Rows.Count; rowCount++) { TextBox textBoxId = (TextBox)gvEventMechanic.Rows[rowCount].Cells[2].FindControl("txtId"); lstStringId.Add(textBoxId.Text); } }       I need to check lstStringId contains any values in dsDuplicate

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> list = ...
DataTable table = ...

var items = new HashSet<string>(list);
var results = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
              where items.Contains(row.Field<string>("YourColumnName"))
              select row;

foreach (var matchingRow in results)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Note: If you need the results to be in the form of another DataTable or DataView (such as for databinding), there are methods for that.

```
var output = results.CopyToDataTable(); // or
var output = results.AsDataView();
```

Comment: This should work. Could also do `table.AsEnumerable().Where(row => items.Contains(row.Field<string>("YourColumnName"))` which is the same thing. The other is more readable though.